# Populating Cells in a tableView from API Call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am forced to use an asynchronous call (I guess closure in swift) to get Data I need using an SDK (APIWrapper). I'm finding that the view is being initalized before I am able to get the data that I need.

So my 1st question to y'all is, how can I get my cells to bring in the data that I need to the table view before the view loads? Then, why would I want to use an asyncronous call at this point

```
import APIWrapper
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let provider = APIWrapper
    var categories = [String]()


    //define number of cells
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        categories = []
        self.getCells()
        print("count " , self.categories.count)
        return(self.categories.count)
    }

    //get number of cells
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "categories")
        cell.textLabel?.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        return(cell)
    }

    private func getCells(){
        provider?.getCategoriesWithCallback { (response, error) -> () in
            if error == nil {
                print("response ", response)
                self.updateTableViewWithCategories(categories: response as! [APIWrapperCategory])
            }
            else {
                print("FUCKK")
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateTableViewWithCategories(categories: [APIWrapperCategory]){
        for category in categories{
             print("category obj " , category)
             print("category name " , category.name)
        }
    }
}
```

The output from my console looks like

```
count  0
count  0
count  0
count  0
response  Optional([<APIWrapperCategory: 0x6000002a0300>])
category obj  <ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6000002a0300>
category name  General
response  Optional([<ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6180002a30c0>])
category obj  <ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6180002a30c0>
category name  General
response  Optional([<ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6180002a30c0>])
category obj  <ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6180002a30c0>
category name  General
response  Optional([<ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6180002a3300>])
category obj  <ZDKHelpCenterCategory: 0x6180002a3300>
category name  General
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting data for your table view from the data source method of the tableview.

To get data from an API call, call `self.getCells()` method in `viewDidLoad()` method  of your view controller like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      //your code here
      //get cells data    
      self.getCells()
 }
```

And add your api response data to table view data source as:

```
  private func updateTableViewWithCategories(categories: [APIWrapperCategory]){
    self. categories = []
    for category in categories{
         print("category obj " , category)
         print("category name " , category.name)
         self. categories.append(category.name)
    }
    //reload table view here
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.yourTableView.reloadData()
    }
 }
```

and change the delegate method as:

```
  //define number of cells
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("count " , self.categories.count)
    return(self.categories.count)
}
```

Comment: Make sure the call to `reloadData` is being done on the main queue.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I have added this.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using `viewWillAppear` and changed a few things on the way data is returned to make the cells populate so here's the code, I hope this can help someone else out

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.getCategoriesFromZendesk()
}


//define number of cells
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("count " , self.categories.count)
    return self.categories.count
}

//get number of cells
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Add Label to the Prototype Cell
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "categories")
    cell.textLabel?.text = categories[indexPath.row]    
    return(cell)
}


private func getCategories(){

    self.categories = []

    provider?.getCategoriesWithCallback { (response, error) -> () in
        if error == nil {
            print("response ", response?.map{($0 as AnyObject as? APIWrapperCategory)?.name ?? ""} ?? "empty")
            self.updateTableViewWithCategories(categories: response as? [APIWrapperCategory])
        }
        else {
            print("FUCKK")
        }
    }
}


private func updateTableViewWithCategories(categories: [APIWrapperCategory]?){
    self.categories = categories?.flatMap{$0.name} ?? []
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```